# How to automatic name documents in SharePoint?

Tags: document-library, content-type

I want all the documents in a document library to be named based on meta tags and the document ID sharepoint give the document. What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Is it for example possible to use a calculated field, to name the document?

```
([Metadata1]&[Metadata2]&[ID] = Document name)
```

Answer (score 1):

no dont use calculated field to do that.

You should set the title (default field to not required).

open sharepoint desinger -> open up list in question -> update the new item form -> remove the title part (label and textbox) -> save

now create a workflow that is kicked off when an item is created and update the title column with whatever meta data you want.

now open up the edit form and disable the title field (read only) -> save

all above is found here:

under the forms area to update the "new item" and "edit item".

under workflows to create the new workflow associated to this list

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there any way to change the filename of the document?

Comment: what file name are you referring to? the forms name?